# Is this Equation correct $\cos^{6} \theta-\sin^{6} \theta=\frac{1}{16}(\cos 6\theta+15\cos 2\theta)$?

Tags: trigonometry

Is this equation correct?
$$\cos^{6} \theta-\sin^{6} \theta=\frac{1}{16}(\cos 6\theta+15\cos 2\theta)$$
I tried to solve it but found that it was not matching sides

Can the possible correction be
$$\cos^{6} \theta+\sin^{6} \theta=\frac{1}{32}(\cos 6\theta+15\cos 2\theta)$$
Let me know this is correct..

Comment: If $\theta = 0$, the LHS of the first equation is $1$ and the RHS is $\frac{1}{16}$.

Comment: The original expression is correct and the $RHS$ at $\theta=0$ is ${1\over16}(1+15)=1$. Maybe it has something to do with the edit?

Answer (score 1):

Both the relations are not satisfied at x=0 . So maybe both the relations are wrong

Answer (score 0):

No it is not always correct.Actually it is correct only if
$\theta =n\cdot \pi-\frac{7\pi}{8}$ or
 $\theta=n\cdot \pi-\frac{3\pi}{8}$

Answer (score 0):

Think about it as this way:

$$\cos^6(x)-\sin^6(x)=\left(\cos^3(x)-\sin^3(x)\right)\left(\cos^3(x)+\sin^3(x)\right)$$ $$=\left(\cos^2(x)-\sin^2(x)\right)\left(1-\cos^2(x)\sin^2(x)\right)$$

Comment: The second bracket should be a minus sign because $\sin^4x+\cos^4x$ is not $1$ but is $1-2\sin^2x\cos^2x$

Comment: @cr001: Oh yes! Thanks for your attention.

Answer (score 0):

$$\cos^6(\theta)-\sin^6(\theta)=(\cos^2(\theta)-\sin^2(\theta))(\cos^4(\theta)+\sin^2(\theta)\cos^2(\theta)+\sin^4(\theta))$$

$$=(\cos(2\theta))(1-\sin^2(\theta)\cos^2(\theta))=(\cos(2\theta))(1-{\sin^2(2\theta)\over4})$$

$$={1\over4}(\cos(2\theta))(3+\cos^2(2\theta))={1\over4}(3\cos(2\theta)+\cos^3(2\theta))$$

$$={1\over4}(\cos(2\theta))(3+\cos^2(2\theta))={1\over4}({15\over4}\cos(2\theta)+{1\over4}(4\cos^3(2\theta)-3\cos(2\theta))$$

$$={1\over16}(15\cos(2\theta)+\cos(6\theta))$$